# Mock pathlib.Path.exists

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pathlib

My Python function creates `pathlib.Path` objects. I want to mock this, so when the code will call `pathlib.Path("/tmp/a").exists()` it will get `True`, and when the code will call `pathlib.Path("/tmp/b").exists()` it will get `False`.

I tried this:

```py
import pathlib
from unittest.mock import patch

def my_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
    print (f" args = {args} , kwargs={kwargs}")
    return True

with patch.object(pathlib.Path, 'exists') as mock_exists:
    mock_exists.side_effect = my_side_effect
    print(pathlib.Path("a").exists())
```

Output:

```
 args = () , kwargs={}
True
```

As you can see, my side effect is not getting any args/kwargs based on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works as expected, because `pathlib.Path.exists` doesn't take any arguments. The path you are interested in is saved in the `Path` object.
Instead of using `side_effect`, you can just patch `pathlib.Path.exists` with your own function that does what you need:

```py
import pathlib
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

def my_exists(self):
    # self is the Path instance, str(Path) returns the path string
    return str(self) == "a"

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_exists(self):
        with patch.object(pathlib.Path, 'exists', my_exists):
            self.assertTrue(pathlib.Path("a").exists())
            self.assertFalse(pathlib.Path("b").exists())
```