# How to monkeypatch Path().exists()

Tags: pytest

How would you `monkeypatch` using the `pytest` framework  the

```py
Path('folder/file.suffix').exists()
```

?
This is the how to do it with `OS` library

```py
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch

monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()
monkeypatch.setattr(os.path, "exists", lambda _: True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock pathlib.Path.exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512401/mock-pathlib-path-exists)

Comment: I would like to use the `pytest` library

Comment: You could just use `monkeypatch.setattr(pathlib.Path, 'exists', lambda _: True)`, doesn't this work?

Comment: No - since it is not a writable attribute

Comment: Not sure what you mean - I just tested it and it works for me. Maybe you can add a bit more context, a minimum reproducible example would help.